# Adding encoded chars to the url breaks htaccess

Tags: url, .htaccess, character-encoding, encode

Here's my code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule page/(.*) index.php?url=$1 [NC]
```

When I access *page/[http://google.com/](http://google.com/_)* = works just fine
When I access *page/http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2F* = server reports 404

Martti Laine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache returns a (somewhat non-intuitive) 404 in cases when you have encoded slashes in the request, but do not have [`AllowEncodedSlashes`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes) set to on. To confirm this is the case, check your error log, which likely contains an entry like this:

> found %2f (encoded '/') in URI
>   (decoded='/page/http://google.com/'),
>   returning 404

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need the `B` ([escape](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags)) flag:

```
RewriteRule page/(.*) index.php?url=$1 [NC,B]
```

That will escape the back-reference ($1) before adding it to the replace string.