# URL-encoded parameter breaks default Zend rewrite rules

Tags: zend-framework, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, urlencode

I'm using the standard Zend `/public/.htaccess` file (shown below).

At the moment I'm attempting to *forward the user* to a specific controller/action, and *supply the on-success-redirect URL as a URL parameter.*

The resulting URL (assembled & encoded via Zend's URL view helper) looks like this:

```
localhost/crop/index/successRedirect/localhost%2Fprofile%2Fbasic
```

However this pattern apparently violates the default, Zend package mod_rewrite rules: accessing the URL yields a standard Apache 404 error; **Zend doesn't receive the request.**

When the final parameter is manually re-formed as follows, the request works as desired:

```
localhost/crop/index/?successRedirect=localhost%2Fprofile%2Fbasic
```

However this requires a hackish, two-step URL generation process. It would be ideal if the URL produced by the view helper worked independently.

**What can be done to permit the url-encoding to pass through?** Any insight would be appreciated!

These are the contents of my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Enabling RewriteLog like so produces no output for the failing pattern:

```
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteLog "<path>/rewrite.log"
```

I've attempted the solutions proposed by the following two Q&A's, with no change:

- [Adding encoded chars to the url breaks htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3388210/adding-encoded-chars-to-the-url-breaks-htaccess) (`AllowEncodedSlashes On`)
- [Mod Rewrite and Using PHP's GET for URL's When not Following the Rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6814977/mod-rewrite-and-using-phps-get-for-urls-when-not-following-the-rules) (use `QSA` directive for rewrite rule)

Comment: This proposed solution also had no effect: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520484/mod-rewrite-urlencoding-an-already-urlencoded-querystring-parameter-any-way-to - add `NE` directive to `RewriteRule`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AllowEncodedSlashes On` fixed this for me, using your exact test URL. However as per http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes, this directive needs to be in either the server configuration or vhost. it doesn't work in the .htaccess file.

Personally I would go with the query string solution. Could you expand on what you mean by this being a two-step URL generation process? I would have thought the syntax would be pretty similar to using the normal URL helper.

Comment: Sure enough. Setting this directive in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` - my original attempt - had no effect. I just tried setting it in the virtual host (`/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`) and it was successful. Thanks!